# Line to Polygon tool doesn't work

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I tried to use tool of QGis, Line to Polygon but it does'nt work.

I tested with close lines in the same direction and I tested with intersection of 4 lines but the result is the same, that's generate an empty Shapefile.

I tested with Saga GIS tool in toolbox but the result is the same.

I've the version 2.14.4 of QGis and this is the link for my file : https://we.tl/l8zPIY8V4S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably some very minute geometric error but you can resolve this by:

1. Run the **Dissolve** tool and enable the *Dissolve all* option (although it doesn't matter much as the layer only contains a single field).
2. Run the **Lines to polygons** tool on the output:

   [image: Result]

---

*Tested on QGIS 2.16.1-Nødebo.*

Comment: It's perfect ! But it's so curious that's no work before. And if lines intersect other lines this technic don't work.

Comment: @Geo-x - Glad it worked! I haven't really examined the shapefile but as long as the lines create a closed 'network', you should be able to create polygons from those.

Comment: I think in fact, Shapefile have a problem but I don't know what. The Shapefile of this example is very simple.

Answer (score 2):

The Polygonize algorithm from the processing toolbox creates the desired polygon with one step.

It can even work with intersecting lines:

[image]

You may have to check the geometry validity before, and make sure that common points really share the same coordinates.

Comment: I didn't know this hide scripts ! Thank you very much. Do you know why this scripts are not in Toobox ?

Comment: Did you still use the `Simple Interface`? This has been removed by now. Make sure you have processing as a core plugin, and not from the Python plugin manager.

Comment: I can add the .py script with Toolbox in part whose name `Scripts > Tools > Add a script from file` and after I've to go to search this script.

Comment: For me, the script was in the toolbox from the start. Not sure what goes wrong on your side.

Comment: In an other french forum a user tell me since QGis 2.16 polygonize doesn't appear. I'm on version 2.14.4 and I don't have this script by default. If I add and launch it, a window appear and close after 1 second without results...

Comment: I tried both 2.16.3 and 2.14.4 on Windows and Ubuntu, and it is present as expected. In the french locale, type `Mise en polygones` in the search bar of the `Traitement` toolbox. Not sure about other OS, when shapely is missing.

Comment: It's perfect AndreJ ! In fact `Mise en polygone` work ! Thank you very much.